# WSL2 I was able to cd into a non-existent folder, how is that possible?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

```
(base) nyck33@LAPTOP-EEVJTJJ4:~$ cd $gatech
(base) nyck33@LAPTOP-EEVJTJJ4:/mnt/f/1_gatechSpring2023$ cd Infosec
(base) nyck33@LAPTOP-EEVJTJJ4:/mnt/f/1_gatechSpring2023/Infosec$ cd ..
(base) nyck33@LAPTOP-EEVJTJJ4:/mnt/f/1_gatechSpring2023$ ls
CN  InfoSec  Loans  ML  ML4T  NetworkSecurity6262  RL  gameAI  renumberVideos.py
(base) nyck33@LAPTOP-EEVJTJJ4:/mnt/f/1_gatechSpring2023$ cd InfoSec
(base) nyck33@LAPTOP-EEVJTJJ4:/mnt/f/1_gatechSpring2023/InfoSec$ cd ..
(base) nyck33@LAPTOP-EEVJTJJ4:/mnt/f/1_gatechSpring2023$ ls -al
total 4
drwxrwxrwx 1 nyck33 nyck33 4096 Jan  4 23:39 .
drwxrwxrwx 1 nyck33 nyck33 4096 Jan 16 09:58 ..
drwxrwxrwx 1 nyck33 nyck33 4096 Jan  4 23:39 CN
drwxrwxrwx 1 nyck33 nyck33 4096 Jan 16 17:08 InfoSec
d--x--x--x 1 nyck33 nyck33 4096 Jan  4 23:39 Loans
d--x--x--x 1 nyck33 nyck33 4096 Jan  1 20:08 ML
d--x--x--x 1 nyck33 nyck33 4096 Jan  4 23:40 ML4T
d--x--x--x 1 nyck33 nyck33 4096 Jan 13 10:01 NetworkSecurity6262
d--x--x--x 1 nyck33 nyck33 4096 Jan  4 23:39 RL
drwxrwxrwx 1 nyck33 nyck33 4096 Jan 15 19:01 gameAI
---------- 1 nyck33 nyck33  885 Dec 11 10:51 renumberVideos.py
(base) nyck33@LAPTOP-EEVJTJJ4:/mnt/f/1_gatechSpring2023$
```

```
(base) nyck33@LAPTOP-EEVJTJJ4:/mnt/f/1_gatechSpring2023$ cd Infosec
(base) nyck33@LAPTOP-EEVJTJJ4:/mnt/f/1_gatechSpring2023/Infosec$ cd ..
```

Is this normal behavior?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Windows APIs are are case-preserving, but not case sensitive (by default, anyway). That means that if you create a file named `FooBar`, then Windows will save it as `FooBar`, but any combination of cases can be used to access it (`foobar`, `foObar`, `FooBAR`, whatever).

You can enable case sensitivity if you want. See the following articles:

- [Per-directory case sensitivity and WSL](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/per-directory-case-sensitivity-and-wsl/)
- [WSL How-to: Adjust case sensitivity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/case-sensitivity)